# add time in seconds in javascript

Tags: javascript, time

i have this function

```
        var countt = count, time = count.data('countdown'), format = count.data('format');
        var Otime = new Date(time), o = {
            serverSync: serverTime,
            until:Otime,
            // demo data set to reset timer, when it's finished
            // change zeroCallback to prefered callback
            zeroCallback: function(options) {
            }
        };
        if(format){
            $.extend(o,{format:format});
        }else{
            $.extend(o,{layout: '{dn} {dl} {hnn}{sep}{mnn}{sep}{snn}'});
        }
        count.countdown(o)
    }
```

i want to add 10 seconds to this `var Otime = new Date(time)` 
i am looking for something like

```
var Otime = new Date(time) + 10 seconds
```

is there an appropriate way to do it?

EDIT:

```
function change_date(count)
    {
        var  serverTime = function() { 
            var time = null; 
            $.ajax({
                url: 'index.php', 
                async: false, 
                dataType: 'text', 
                data:{
                    page:'__request',
                    module:'PSF_auctions',
                    action:'get_server_time'
                },
                success: function(text) { 
                    time = new Date(text); 
                }, 
                error: function(http, message, exc) { 
                    time = new Date(); 
                }
            }); 
            return time; 
        }
```

this returns time variable, which is the current system time

Comment: What is `time` variable?

Comment: it brings system time

Comment: Try this `var t = new Date(time); t.setSeconds(t.getSeconds() + 10);`

Comment: What is its type (`number`/ `string`/ ...)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var Otime = new Date(time)
Otime.setSeconds(Otime.getSeconds() + 10);
```